Posting data from a form using Javascript / AJaX to a Tomcat jsp page returns null field values
Using Javascript to build a form with POST. When the form is submitted using AJaX to a Tomcat jsp page (or a servlet), the jsp page isn't retrieving form data.
request.getParameter() is instead returning null.
Also getting the same result when attempting to POST the form data using 'await fetch(test.jsp)'
A test javascript function to POST data to a Tomcat jsp page:
function send() {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("recId", "5");

    xhr.addEventListener('load', handleReturn);
    xhr.open('POST', 'test.jsp', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(formData);
    // xhr.send("recId=5");
    return xhr;
}

But in the target script 'test.jsp' -
String rId = request.getParameter("recId");
is returning null. Expecting '5'
This is the payload reported by Dev Tools:
------WebKitFormBoundarysRv6NCasQdzagUns
Content-Disposition: form-data; name: "recId"

5
------WebKitFormBoundarysRv6NCasQdzagUns-

Have also tried using a form with a field named recId, eg:
formData = new FormData(this-is-a-form);
xhr.send(formData);
Same result.
String rId = request.getParameter("recId");
returns null instead of '5'
Have tried all the hints I could find online, and the documentation I found suggests this should work.
What am I missing?
However, this (not using a form) does work:
function send() {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // const formData = new FormData();
    // formData.append("recId", "5");

    xhr.addEventListener('load', handleReturn);
    xhr.open('POST', 'test.jsp', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // xhr.send(formData);
    xhr.send("recId=5");
    return xhr;
}

This is the payload reported by Dev Tools:
recId=5

Thanks, the issue now resolved but with a different approach.
Instead of annotating the servlet with @MultipartConfig I updated the apps META-INF/context.xml to enable allowCasualMultipartParsing:

Then POSTing the form data to the servlet worked:
function send() {
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("recId", "5");
xhr.open('POST', 'test-servlet', true);
xhr.send(formData);
}
request.getParameter("recId") now returns the value
